# My NFC writing app cannot write into a tag

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

Sorry to ask again, I am working on creating an android app to write data into a tag, it can sense a tag and open automatically by using AAR, however, it cannot write data into the file after I have filled in the EdiText columns and click the button, I have tried different ways including declare the onclick action in layout.xml file, or using the onclicklistener, but none of it works, so can anyone help me take a look where is the problem?

```
public class Writer extends Activity{

NfcAdapter mAdapter;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
IntentFilter mWriteTagFilters[];
boolean mWriteMode;
Tag detectedTag;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_writer);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SetTag();
            }
        });
    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    mWriteTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };
    //Intent intent = getIntent();

}

private void enableTagWriteMode(){
    mWriteMode = true;
    mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, mWriteTagFilters, null);
}

private void disableTagWriteMode(){
    mWriteMode = false;
    mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

public void SetTag(){
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message1);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message2);
    String message1 = editText1.getText().toString();
    String message2 = editText2.getText().toString();
    byte[] textBytes1 = message1.getBytes();
    byte[] textBytes2 = message2.getBytes();
    NdefRecord textRecord1 = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, 
            NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[]{}, textBytes1);
    NdefRecord textRecord2 = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, 
            NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[]{}, textBytes2);
    NdefMessage mNdefMessage = new NdefMessage(
        new NdefRecord[]{
                textRecord1,
                textRecord2,
                NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("android.reader")
        }
    );
    writeTag(mNdefMessage, detectedTag);    
}

public static void writeTag(NdefMessage message, Tag tag){
    int size = message.toByteArray().length;
    try {
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if (ndef != null){
            ndef.connect();
            if (ndef.isWritable() && ndef.getMaxSize() > size)
                ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
            ndef.close();
        }else{
            NdefFormatable format = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
            if (format != null) {
                try {
                    format.connect();
                    format.format(message);
                }catch(IOException e){

                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()))
        detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);        
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    disableTagWriteMode();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    enableTagWriteMode();
}

/*@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message1);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message2);
    String message1 = editText1.getText().toString();
    String message2 = editText2.getText().toString();
    byte[] textBytes1 = message1.getBytes();
    byte[] textBytes2 = message2.getBytes();
    NdefRecord textRecord1 = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, 
            message1.getBytes(), new byte[]{}, textBytes1);
    NdefRecord textRecord2 = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, 
            message2.getBytes(), new byte[]{}, textBytes2);
    NdefMessage mNdefMessage = new NdefMessage(
        new NdefRecord[]{
                textRecord1,
                textRecord2,
                NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("android.reader")
        }
    );
    writeTag(mNdefMessage, detectedTag);
}*/


}
```

Following is the layot file:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message1"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message1" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message2"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message2" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Recently my code can only launch, but it cannot write data into the tag, thus when the device sense the tag again, it will open this app again instead of another reading tag app I written.

Answer (score 0):

Your IntentFilter is clearly not matching, making the ForegroundDispatch not work.
In your `onCreate()`, try adding `tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);`. I think that will do the trick.

Comment: But if it is not working, why it can launch after the tag being sensed, or this steps is not related to the foreground dispatch? So because it does not resume at all, so the writing mode has not been enabled and hence nothing can be written in? Just want to clear my concept first

Comment: Good question. It is launched because of the intent filter in the manifest file, I think. Depending on the `launchMode` of the Activity (e.g. singleTop), the resulting call wil be `onCreate()`, `onNewIntent()` or perhaps `onResume()` (I don't know exactly; you can check by displaying Toast messages in the various functions or logging to logcat.)

Comment: ok,thx guy, I try to output some messages first to find out the flow of the activity first